# Run Combobox code only when unique value is found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, combobox

Maybe someone has already done this and I just can't find it.

Here's the scenario .....
I have a combobox filled with a large range of names for example and using the AfterUpdate event it works the way it's supposed to in that, as the user is typing into it, it will keep matching based on the characters typed in.
When the user is satisfied with the match found (or has just selected a name from the drop-down) they have to press the "Enter" key and my code continues on from the "AfterUpdate" event.

My ultimate goal is that I don't want them to have to press the "Enter" key

I've coded the "Change" event to call the "AfterUpdate" event so that when they select from the drop-down, everything works smoothly.

If they begin typing into the Combobox though it finds a match on the 1st letter, fills in the Combobox and runs with whatever it found.

Is there a way to prevent the Combobox match complete to not match unless a unique entry is found in the drop-down range?

Example:
My range includes "Joseph" "Johnny" & "Jerry"
What it does now is as soon as I enter a "J" it finds "Joseph", fills in the combobox and my change event calls the AfterUpdate event using "Joseph" as the Combobox value.

What I'd like it to do is after the "J", do nothing as there are 3 other entries beginning with "J" in my ListFill range.

Continue with the "o", and still do nothing as "Jo" is still not unique in my list

When I add the "s" or the "h", see that it's unique, fill the Combobox with the full matched entry and only then have the Change" event call the "AfterUpdate" event

```
Private Sub ProjMgr_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ProjMgr, Range("PMTemp"), 0)) Then
        ' User selected one of the existing PM's. 
        ' Do my code here.
    Else
        ' User entered a name that's not listed as a PM for this Client
        ' Run the code to Add a PM
End Sub
Private Sub ProjMgr_Change()
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ProjMgr, Range("PMTemp"), 0)) Then
    ' If the User selects from the Combobox, run the AfterUpdate code
    ' so they don't have to press the "Enter" key
    ' If they begin typing into the Combobox, I don't want to continue
    ' until there's a unique match to what's in Range("PMTemp")
         ProjMgr_AfterUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Posting your code is more likely to get you suggestions...

Comment: Added the code as suggested Tim. I guess this is more of a logic or procedural question as there are probably a number of ways to accomplish it, if I could only figure out one of them.

Comment: I'm not super great w/ arrays, but I'm picturing an array that gets continually resized w/ only remaining options that constantly looks for only one remaining match.

Comment: Quick question. Why are you using `AfterUpdate()` or the `Change()` event and not a command button? Wouldn't it be much simpler? Also when you type `j` in combobox, the `AfterUpdate()` will **not** fire. This event will fire when you leave the combobox and say click on a textbox. This event works more like the `_Exit()` event. What is causing the macro to run is not the `AfterUpdate()` but the `Change()` event.

Comment: Also if you do not want combobox to autofill, change the `MatchEntry` property to `fmMatchEntryNone` in design time. This may solve your problem because when you type "J", the `Change()` event will kick off the line `If Not IsError(Application.Match("J", Range("PMTemp"), 0)) Then` but remember this may give you false positives. For example if you have 2 names **John** and **Johnny** and you want to select **Johnny**, the code will give unexpected results with **John**.

Comment: I do hope that you still retain the possibility to select an item with up-down arrow keys, and hitting Enter. Think of e.g. `Abraham Lincoln` and `Abraham Lincolns`. After typing the last "n" you still have two possibilities and the only way to select the shorter is to e.g. hit Enter. Or another case: the names as before, are the only ones beginning with an "A". User might not like, that they have to type until the "s" before that name is auto selected.

Comment: Finally, a third scenario. User focuses on the keyboard while typing and doesn't notice a typing error. The wrong person get autoselected. A confirmation with the Enter key is perhaps not so bad after all. (It doesn't save the user that automatically hits the Enter after the other keys, but your program can not be blamed for the wrong selection)

Comment: What about just counting with `Countif` if the value in `ProjMgr` appears exactly 1 in range `PMTemp`? That way you would know it's a unique entry and then proceed.

Comment: I would have thought that this was something that would have already been figured out as I believe it could be quite useful.
Siddharth. The MatchEntry is what I want. If user selects an entry, from the range, just run the code and continue on. No extra steps (or command button) necessary. 
Yes, the Exit event would behave similar to the AfterUpdate but it involves an extra step. I want to eliminate the step of pressing and keys or moving somewhere else.
Selecting works just the way I need it to. If they type in a string of characters that appears in only one entry of the range, do the same

Comment: Tom. Yes, there would be rare instances of the Abe Lincoln and Lincolns but for the bulk of the data, 3 or 4 characters would get a unique match. 
As for the 3rd scenario, wrong selection, that can happen anyway. There is a reset button for them to start over if they make a mistake. The combobox box doesn't go away with my code, it just displays further info regarding their selection. They are supposed to look at it to see if what came up is what they want and if not, there's a reset button.

Comment: FF&B&B. That is the direction that I was playing with. With KeyPress I can capture the characters typed into a string and check for matches in the range. I'll likely need a minimum character count too (maybe 3 or 4)
If more than 1 match, don't call the A/U event. Combobox will fill in the 1st match but allow the user to continue typing characters into it looking for further matches. If they've entered the minimum count and a unique match is found, call the A/U event and if no match is found after satisfying the minimum count, they'll be forced to press enter taking them to my "AddNew" code.